# Node Sass version 7.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app, node-sass

I have a react project I created using `create-react-app` And I was trying to use sass in react by installing `node-sass` for react.js

But I keep getting an error saying It's incompatible.

```
Node Sass version 7.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0
```

### Node Sass version 7.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0

What is the problem?

[image: Error: 'node-sass' version 5.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0]
[image: Node Sass version 7.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0]
[image: Node Sass version 6.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 in React.js]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Install `sass` instead

The library `node-sass` is now deprecated. So you can use the new version `sass`

Do the following

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

Works with no further changes

Answer (score 4):

I've also encountered this problem in my nodejs project.
The error says ***"Error: Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0."***"

Here's my current node & npm version:
`npm version: 8.1.2`
`node version: v16.13.1`

And my current node-sass & sass-loader:
`sass-loader@7.1.0`
`node-sass@7.0.1`

**My solution that works:**
I just install the following modules:
`npm install -D sass-loader@10.2.0`
`npm install -D node-sass@6.0.1`

Other references:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/945#issuecomment-836976664

Comment: You, saved me!!

Answer (score 0):

The following errors occur only when there is a version mismatch. with `node-sass` and installed node.js

## Node Sass version 7.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0

- For this error, you can remove your node-sass and install node-sass version 6 using `npm install node-sass@6.0`

## Node Sass version 6.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 in React.js

- When you installed node sass 6.0 on node.js of version 14, you get the following error. you can fix it by installing `npm install node-sass@4.14.1`

Or to avoid the error for all versions

You can use `sass` instead of `node-sass` or install the right node sass version